# Access 2013 SQL, searching for : in a specified cell

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am working on a SQL statement for an Access 2013 database. I have two tables as similar to these two:

T1:

```
ticketID         endResult
1
2
```

T2:

```
ticketID         Description
1                Return: other text
2                some description
```

The goal is to update T1.endResult with `Fixed: Return` whenever there is a ':' in the T2.Description column. This is all being done in Access 2013, using SQL statements. Currently I am doing the following:

```
UPDATE T1
INNER JOIN T2 ON T1.ticketID = T2.ticketID
SET T1.endResult = ('Fixed: ' & LEFT(T2.Description, :))
WHERE (T1.endResult IS NULL AND (InStr(T2.Description, :,1)))
```

Whenever I run this, access prompts me to input the value of : . How could I search the description just for that one symbol? Now that I use the LEFT of : as well as there could be other values instead of Return that could be returned and still be valid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple of things that are wrong.

`'Fixed: ' & LEFT(T2.Description, :)`
- you need to tell it how many letters to return from **Description**.

Use `INSTR` to find the position of **:** within the text:
`'Fixed: ' & LEFT(Description, INSTR(Description,":")-1)`

`(T2.description IS NULL AND (InStr(T2.Description, :,1)))`
 - **Description** can't be both **NULL** and contain a **:**.

Try:

```
UPDATE T1 INNER JOIN T2 ON T1.ticketID = T2.ticketID
SET endresult = 'Fixed: ' & LEFT(Description, INSTR(Description,":")-1)
WHERE INSTR(Description,":")<>0
```

`INSTR(Description,":")` will return the position of the text within the string, or 0 if it isn't present.  The `WHERE` clause just needs to check that INSTR is returning something other than 0.

You don't have to fully qualify the field names, except in the join, if they only appear in one of the tables.  **Description** only appears in **T2**, so the SQL will know that.

Comment: Great, thank you so much! Note about the IS NULL, I meant to put in T1.endResult and not T2.description, either way the end result remains good. Thanks again!